# How do i clone svn repo on specific port

Tags: git, git-svn, msysgit

I'm using msysgit on windows

on old repo i had no problems with this command

```
git svn clone -s --username=XXX https://URL
```

but repo has moved and now the url is like that: svn://URL:port
how can i set this port number ?
using

```
git svn clone svn://URL:port
```

results with 'mkdir ... not a directory' error, and without port it can't find the repository

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by simply removing the port number from the svn URL.  This worked because I had an entry in my ssh config for that URL that already mapped it to a specific port.  If you don't have it configured, the entry in your ssh config would look something like this:

```
Host my.svnrepo.com
     User your.name
     Port 321
```

Answer (score 1):

If the server does not accept ssh connection you may be better of trying :

```
git svn clone "svn://my.svnrepo.com:port" mydir
```

The repo is then saved in mydir avoiding the mkdir error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-p ####` or `-e "p ####"`? Those would be my 2 guesses.

Comment: svn://<host>:<port>/... *is* a proper svn: URL. If it's not working with git-svn, then that's git-svn's problem. There may be some "quoting" syntax to use though. Might be worth trying a trailing slash.